# ANSI C variable declaration syntax "+0"?

Tags: c, syntax, definition

I have to work on the PC with foreign C code (originally running on embedded HW), which I am not allowed to modify.

Some variable declarations in one .h file look like this:

```
extern int variableA;
extern variableB;
extern variableC+0;
```

- Declaration of variableA is clear.
- Declaration of variableB passes the compiler, the type is assumed to be an int.
- Declaration of variableC fails.

**Question:**
What kind of syntax is used for the declaration of variableC? How can I make the compiler to accept it (no code modification allowed)? Is this even a valid C syntax?

The compiler used for the project is the VS2008 internal compiler.

**Update:**

I traced back the includes, and no #define is changing that syntax. FYI, that code is from an airborne HW, and compiles correctly (with the compilers for the HW). The variable is used as a regular variable in the code parts available to me:

```
variableC+0 = otherVar;
```

Thanks for the replies, this then really seems to be invalid standard C code, only working for that specific compiler.

Comment: This does not look like a valid syntax at all. At least not in ANSI C

Comment: What other information do you have? How is variableC used later in the code? Could it be a macro, so that `extern variableC+0;` expands to something like `extern a=3+0;`? Do you have evidence this code ever compiled successfully? Is it in code that is not compiled because of preprocessor conditionals?

Comment: The statement `int a + 0;` also doesn't make sense, and that looks like a similar construction.

Comment: Do you have a custom tool that pre-processes your sources before feeding them to your C++ compiler? This code looks like a "hard" syntax error.

Comment: minor nitpick: these are *declarations*, not definitions

Comment: Was the original source code written with non-ASCII characters, subject to broken encoding? Was the code additionally processed prior to compilation? Are you sure this isn't a "job security" thing? Are you sure the source code isn't corrupt due to hardware/software failure?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax doesn't make any sense in C standard.

Comment: Maybe because *the answer is not useful* even though it's correct (i didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f8y25b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) this is not valid syntax.

```
 identifier:

    nondigit

    identifier nondigit

    identifier digit

nondigit: one of

    _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

digit: one of

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

No plus at all. 
I think, plus sign will be parsed to sum expression by any parser of C-like language.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance, this then must be a certain syntax only valid on the specific compiler. The code is from an airborne hw, and yes, the code compiles there. In the code parts availabe to me, the variable "variableC+0" is handled as a valid variable, like variableC+0 = otherVariable;